# Installing maven to use through command line

Tags: maven, windows-7-x64

I'm installing maven for the first time, on a windows 7 laptop.
I want to be able to use maven through the command line, I have downloaded and unzipped maven 3.1.0, from the instructions I received it says to add %M2_HOME%\bin to the Path environment variable to make Maven available in the command line!
However when I unzipped maven there is no bin folder??
any thoughts or solutions?

Comment: Please post the link where you downloaded it; I just checked the ones from http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi and all files have a apache-maven-version directory, which contains a bin directory

Comment: I downloaded from here - http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi , maven 3.1.0 binary zip which has the bin folder now, but when I set the environment system variable to this bin folder and check the mvn --version in the cmd line, it says mvn is not recognised as a command

Comment: did you set M2_HOME correctly? what does echo %M2_HOME% display? you may have to open a new command prompt

Comment: Yes I set it to the correct path, when i run the echo %M2_HOME% I get the correct path to my bin folder

Comment: when i run mvn --version now, it is saying that JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory?

Comment: but when I run java -version it works correctly??

Comment: maven requires that JAVA_HOME is defined, as of point 6 of installation instructions